# PHP: Error in return date between two date

Tags: php, date

I've tried to make a function that will return all dates between two dates.

My function is like this :

```
function dateRange($first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $format = 'd/m/Y' ) { 

    $dates = array();
    $current = strtotime($first);
    $last = strtotime($last);

    while( $current <= $last ) { 

        $dates[] = date($format, $current);
        $current = strtotime($step, $current);
    }

    return $dates;
}
```

And I call it like this :

```
$duration = dateRange('25/08/2014', '28/08/2014', $step = '+1 day', $format = 'd/m/Y' );
```

It needs to return each date in an array like this :-

```
array("25/08/2014", "26/08/2014", "27/08/2014", "28/08/2014");
```

It return wrong date in an array like this :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => 01/01/1970
)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: And what it returns now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use DateTime and DateInterval to achieve this with something like this:

```
function dateRange($first, $last, $step='P1D', $format='d/m/Y', $timezone='Europe/London')
{
    $dateObj = new DateTime($first, new DateTimeZone($timezone));
    $endDateObj = new DateTime($last, new DateTimeZone($timezone));
    $dateAry = array();
    $dateAry[]=$dateObj->format($format);
    while($dateObj->format($format) != $endDateObj->format($format)){
        $dateObj->add(new DateInterval($step));
        $dateAry[]=$dateObj->format($format);
    }
    return $dateAry;
}

$dates = dateRange('2014-08-25','2014-08-28');
print_r($dates);
```

UPDATE: Also, do not use the format d/m/Y for $first and $last as it's not supported.  You can output in that format though if you wish to.

Comment: its show me this error `Call to undefined method DateTime::add()`

Comment: @adsman, you need to be using >= PHP 5.3 for this to work.  What version are you using?

Comment: I have this array output like :-

    Array
    (
        [0] => 25-08-2014
        [1] => 26-08-2014
        [2] => 27-08-2014
        [3] => 28-08-2014
    )

I need to convert it like :-

    $duration = array("25/08/2014", "26/08/2014", "27/08/2014");

How can i do that?

Comment: It should output using the format specified in the fourth argument $format and does for me in my testing.

Comment: To assign it to $duration, just run $duration = dateRange('2014-08-05','2014-08-28');

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that format `25/08/2014` is not supported by `strtotime`.
Here's list of supported formats: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

So as you can see one of valid formats is `m/d/y`, so you can call your function like:

```
dateRange('08/25/2014', '08/28/2014');  // month and day swap
```

or

```
dateRange('25.08.2014', '28.08.2014');  // dots instead slashes
```